# how to Return productid in this example mysql?

Tags: mysql

how to Return productid who those filterid equal x and y.

this [image: execute query] is select and return table

query :

```
SELECT p.product_id,pf.filter_id
FROM  oc_product p 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_filter pf 
on p.product_id=pf.product_id
where p.product_id in(96621,97026) and pf.filter_id in (1901,1855 )
group by p.product_id,pf.filter_id
```

The result of the processing:

```
product_id  filter_id
96621           1855
96621           1901
97026           1901
```

but i want to get `product_id` who `filter_id=1855 and filter_id=1901`.

want to show `only product_id=96621` and `not return product_id=97026`

main query :

```
SELECT p.product_id
FROM oc_category_path cp 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c 
ON (cp.category_id = p2c.category_id)
LEFT JOIN oc_product_filter pf 
ON (p2c.product_id = pf.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product p 
ON (pf.product_id = p.product_id)
LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd 
ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s 
ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE pd.language_id = 2 AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = 0
AND cp.path_id = 86125
AND pf.filter_id in(1901,1855)
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY p.price DESC, p.sort_order
```

try and test:

1.@GordThompson:

[this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdCZY.png)

2.@Edward Mendez

[this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw5hE.png)

Comment: Do you want one record for each `filter_id` with minimum `product_id` or what ??

Comment: `SELECT p.product_id FROM ... group by p.product_id having count(*) = 2`.

Comment: `where p.product_id in(96621,97026) and pf.filter_id in (1901,1855 )
group by p.product_id having count(*) = 2 ` but this return only `row 1`

Comment: dear @Susang , i want to get `product_id` who `filter_id=1855 and filter_id=1901`

Comment: @KoroshMan1989 Then you need to post more meaningfull sample data and expected result. I don't understand why you would want to select data that you allready know.

Comment: filter data , checkbox select with '(value speed =20 by filterid=1855) and    (value wieght=30 byfilterid=1901 )' . but show products with ' value speed=30 and wieght=30 and so products with value speed=20 and wieght=30' .in fact  'OR'

Answer (score 0):

Use OR instead of AND clause .

WHERE product_id in () OR filter_id in () OR product_id not in ()

Comment: thanks.I want the command to be variable. These numbers are examples.

Comment: You can’t directly have variable in sql. Variables can be used through programming languages or pl/sql

Comment: query in php and this query example

Comment: if 1000product_id exist that filterid=1901 then remove product id or not in?

Comment: Check it using “?” In your php code where every the example values are present replace it with “?” . I’m not a php developer but can tell that some wildcard characters is used . “?” Is used in java programming.

Comment: part of php code : ` public function getProducts($data = array()) {
  $sql = "SELECT p.product_id`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the product_id from your IN clause for 97026. Also remove the group by since there are no aggregating functioning.

```
SET @product_id = xxx
SET @filter_id = xxx

SELECT p.product_id,pf.filter_id
FROM  oc_product p 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_filter pf 
on p.product_id=pf.product_id
where p.product_id in(@product_id) and pf.filter_id in (filter_id)
#group by p.product_id,pf.filter_id
```

Comment: I want the command to be variable. These numbers are examples.

Comment: My only thought would be to set variables at the top of the query that could be changed out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of product_id values that have both filter_id=1901 and filter_id=1855 you can use

```sql
SELECT product_id
FROM oc_product_filter
WHERE filter_id IN (1901,1855)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

or, if the table may have more than one instance of a specific filter_id for a given product_id you can use

```sql
SELECT t.product_id
FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT product_id, filter_id
        FROM oc_product_filter
    ) t
WHERE t.filter_id IN (1901,1855)
GROUP BY t.product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Dear @GordThompson , not work for me, select in 250000 rows.with select return 1901 or 1855

Comment: @KoroshMan1989 - I don't understand your comment. Are you saying that the query completes and returns no rows? ... returns too many rows? ... hangs and does not complete?

Comment: retruns 5 rows with product_id with filter_id 1901 or 1855

Comment: correct for example but not correct for main query in question