# how to dynaminc pivot or same way for this query of mysql?

Tags: mysql

not Appropriate solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846872/how-to-return-productid-in-this-example-mysql) but now any solution for dynamic(Important and essential) pivot or other way , this return table?

execute bottom query is select and return table

query :

```
SELECT p.product_id,pf.filter_id
FROM  oc_product p 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_filter pf 
on p.product_id=pf.product_id
where p.product_id in(96621,97026) and pf.filter_id in (1901,1855 )
group by p.product_id,pf.filter_id
```

The result of the processing:

```
product_id  filter_id
96621           1855
96621           1901
97026           1901
97026           1610
```

i want to result this :

```
product_id  filter_id
96621           1855
96621           1901
```

but result this :

```
  product_id        filter_id
    96621           1855,1901  
    97026           1901,1610
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GROUP_CONCAT to pivot the table :

```
SELECT p.product_id,GROUP_CONCAT(pf.filter_id)
FROM  oc_product p 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_filter pf 
on p.product_id=pf.product_id
where p.product_id in(96621,97026) and pf.filter_id in (1901,1855 )
group by p.product_id
```

which will return this:

```
  product_id        filter_id
    96621           1855,1901  
    97026           1901,1610
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Post your questions. We are here to help each other :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846872/how-to-return-productid-in-this-example-mysql